# model in MVC helper is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

this my view, I catch an error in

`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FacebookId)` **model is null**

But in the var `@Model`, I have my viewModel with all values

This my view:

```
@model Registration.Front.Web.Models.RegistrationViewModel
    @using Registration.Domain.Entities.Enum;
    @using Registration.Front.Web.Helpers;
    @{
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

    }
    <h2>Registration</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


        <fieldset>
            @{string visibleFb = (!Model.FBParam) ? "display:none" : "display:inline";
                <div id="fb" style="@visibleFb">
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        FacebookId
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FacebookId)
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: can we see the definition for Registration.Front.Web.Models.RegistrationViewModel

Comment: Make sure in your ViewModel:Registration.Front.Web.Models.RegistrationViewModel you have FacebookID defined as:        public string FacebookId { get; set; }

Comment: Yes is a public property, i have a getter and setter

Comment: Can you post your Controller code where you are populating the RegistrationViewModel? And as @AmitApollo said, the class code for RegistrationViewModel.

Comment: You need to show us your Get method

Comment: please post your action method also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to write it as

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => Model.FaceBookId) //<--Note the uppercase "M"
```

So model is just a lamda variable, while Model points to whatever is declared as `@model`

You can see that in the Watch window it's Model, not model, that you're interested in here.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your Action method. Are you returning populated model from you Action ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you note that you did not get that error for Model.FBParam and for Model.Facebookid?
This Means your FacebookId property is nullable and is sent null from action. Also use specific kind of control by your data type like dropdown for int with reference or textbox for string jetc.